How to dynamically increase the number of cells in GrapesJS Plugin Toolbox after updating the grid?
I'm using the GrapesJS Plugin Toolbox to build custom grids in my project. I can successfully define a grid layout and update it. However, after updating the grid, I'm struggling to find a way to dynamically increase the number of cells in the toolbox.
I have a grid set up with, say, 3x3 cells. After updating the grid to a new structure (e.g., 4x4), I want to add more cells to the toolbox and allow users to manipulate these new cells. However, I'm not sure how to handle the dynamic increase in the number of cells within the toolbox after the grid has been updated.
Has anyone faced this issue or knows how to programmatically increase the number of cells in the GrapesJS toolbox after the grid has already been updated?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
